# How to store different information in two different tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, session

I have two different tables in MySQL- one that stores account info (usernames, email, password) and one that stores names of classes they typed inside the field box. So basically, once the user clicks "register" they are brought to the page "class_creation.php" where they type their classes- that information is supposed to be stored in the "classes" table inside MySQL after the user clicks the "submit" button. Then the user is directed to a page called "signup.php" where they enter their account info (username, email, password) and the info from signup.php gets stored inside the MySQL table "users". The second page, signup.php successfully stores its data inside the "users" table- however the "class_creation.php" does not store any data inside its table- and everything is empty. I'm not sure if its a connection issue to phpmyadmin? I tried editing the connection file but nothing I tried seemed to work.

//This is the connection file- I'm using it to connect both the signup.php page and the class_creation.php page to the MySQL database. Its called: "dbh.inc.php"

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $dBUsername = "root";
    $dBPassword = "";
    $dBName = "loginsystem";
    $class1 = $_POST['class1'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_classes (class1) VALUES ('class1')";

    enter code here

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);
    if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

//This is the backend file I'm using for the class creation page- its called: "class.inc.php"

```
<?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require 'dbh.inc.php';
    require 'login.inc.php';


    $class1 = $_POST['class1'];


    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);    

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $class1);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    header("Location../signup.php");


    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

//And finally this is the "class_creation.php" code, used as the layout file for the textfields

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="signup.php" method="POST">

            <input type="text" name="class1" placeholder="" />
            <input type="text" name="class2" placeholder="" />
            <input type="text" name="class3" placeholder="" /> 
            <input type="text" name="class4" placeholder="" />

            <input type="text" name="class5" placeholder="" />
            <input type="text" name="class6" placeholder="" />
            <input type="text" name="class7" placeholder="" />
            <input type="text" name="class8" placeholder="" />

            <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

The info typed in by the user inside the class_creation.php page should appear in the MySQL database- but clearly I must be doing something wrong. Any ideas? The signup.php file seems to store its own data just fine inside the "users" table- let me know if you need to see those files as well but I believe the error is some where within these files.

Comment: You store an `INSERT` statement in a variable called `$sql`, but you never use that variable or execute that statement anywhere...

Comment: phpMyAdmin is *not* your database. MySQL is. phpMyAdmin is just a tool to make managing your database easier. That's a very basic fundamental distinction that you should know *before* you start working with databases.

Comment: I refer to it as my database because it comes with MariaDB and MySQL. And besides- I’m talking about two tables inside PHPmyadmin.

Comment: @DouglasstheDog: No, you're talking about two tables in MySQL.  PHPmyadmin is a tool you use to manage your database.  The reason these distinctions are important is because knowing the terminology of the tools you're using will help you research problems, understand solutions, and generally interact with other developers.

Comment: Ah ok. Also- what is the major flaw with the code? Is it that I’m missing some sort of function or did I not use on appropriately? I didn’t execute the $sql variable I believe

Comment: I suggest you check-out the examples given here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Is there a specific place or website you guys recommend for learning basic PHP skills like this? Instead of just searching on YouTube for good videos?

Comment: So....any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In your `class.inc.php`, you can do something like:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require 'dbh.inc.php';
    require 'login.inc.php';

    $class1 = $_POST['class1'];

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);    

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $class1);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    header("Location../signup.php");

  }
```